# Integrate Library module built with Kotlin Coroutines dependency issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-library, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I am building a library module that using coroutines.

My library do the following:

1. get config from the app module
2. create a fragment that implemented CoroutineScope (ContentListingFragment)
3. ContentListingFragment handle all it's process fetching data from the network and show them

from the app module:
We should able to get an instance from the ContentListingFragment and add it to a container

The issue: when I am building the app, I am getting the following error:

```
Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
    class nabed.apps.nabedutilslibrary.ui.base.ContentListingFragment, unresolved supertypes: kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
```

below is the library module build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-rules.pro'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    }
}

androidExtensions{
    experimental = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'

    // Navigation
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:$navigation_version"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:$navigation_version"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigation_version"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigation_version"


    //Kotlin Coroutines
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.0.0-RC1"


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

How to handle this without changes on the app module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the dependencies declaration in your library's `build.gradle`:

```
//Kotlin Coroutines
api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.0"
api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.0.0-RC1"
```

`api` keyword will expose these dependencies to the app module

Answer (score 0):

****put this code in build.gradel file in dependencies block and click on sync****

//Kotlin Coroutines

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.0"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to use Coroutines in the app module but would like to use it in the library, decision with `api` dependencies not the best one. In this way your app module will be also dependent on Coroutines.

I think, better to remove `CoroutineScope` implementation from `ContentListingFragment` and create `CoroutineScope` object as a `ContentListingFragment` member.

```
class ContentListingFragment : Fragment() {

    private val job = Job()
    private val coroutineScope = object : CoroutineScope {
        override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
            get() = job + Dispatchers.IO

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        coroutineScope.launch { ... }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroy()
        job.cancelChildren()
    }
}
```

Also, `LifecycleScope` form [lifecycle-runtime-ktx](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines) may be a the easiest solution. It will remove `CoroutineScope` creation boilerplate code.

```
class ContentListingFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch { ... }
    }
}
```